# Highcharts generate column chart from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, charts, highcharts

I am reading XML to feed data to Highcharts(Below is my xml).

Trying to build a **column** chart, and a **drilldown** event to generate a **area** chart in a separate `<div>`.
Its easier to hardcode the values and draw the chart.but i dont understand how to perform it using jquery.

I am having a hard time to push the `name` and `y` value of the individual object  to `data` .(for the column chart)

Can anyone please tell me how to pass the value for Column Chart.Thanks so much in Advance.

my XML:

```
<chart>
    <categories>
        <browser>MSIE</browser>
        <browser>FF</browser>
    </categories>
    <ChartSeries>
          <series>
               <name>MSIE</name>
               <value>56</value>
                    <drilldown>
                    <date>
                        <item>01-Apr-16</item>
                        <item>02-Apr-16</item>
                        <item>03-Apr-16</item>
                    </date>
                     <data>
                        <point>13.52</point>
                        <point>5.43</point>
                        <point>1.58</point>
                     </data>
               </drilldown>
         </series>
         <series>
               <name>FF</name>
               <value>67</value>
                <drilldown>
                    <date>
                       <item>01-May-16</item>
                       <item>02-May-16</item>
                       <item>03-May-16</item>
                       <item>04-May-16</item>
                       </date>
                    <data>
                       <point>9.91</point>
                       <point>0.50</point>
                       <point>0.36</point>
                       <point>0.32</point>
                    </data>
               </drilldown>
          </series>
    </ChartSeries>
</chart>
```

My code:

```
var options={
    chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
    xAxis: {
              categories : []
            },
    series : [{
                name:'Browsers',
                data:[]
            }],
   drilldown:{}
};
$.get(url, function(xml) {
    var $xml = $(xml);

    $xml.find('categories browser').each(function(i, category) { 
            options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
    });

    $xml.find('ChartSeries series').each(function(i, series) {
         var pointOptions = {
             name : $(series).find('name').text(),
             y: Number($(series).find('value').text()),
             drilldown: $(series).find('name').text()
          };
          options.series[0].data.push(pointOptions);  
    });
   var drilldown={
       series:[]
   };

   $xml.find('ChartSeries series').each(function(i, series) {
        var pointOptionsDrill = {
            id : $(series).find('name').text(),
            data:[] 
        };

      $(series).find('drilldown').each(function(i,point){
            pointOptionsDrill.data.push([$(series).find('date item').text(),Number($(series).find('data point').text())])
      });
      drilldown.series.push(pointOptionsDrill);  

});
    options.drilldown=drilldown;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});

  <div id="container" style="width: 100%;  height:100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confuse a series with a point. What you actually have in the xml file in `<series>` is a point which should be pushed to data array.

So you have one series named 'Browsers' and 2 points which are named 'FF' and 'MSIE' which belong to categories (defined before).

```
$.get(url, function(xml) {
  var $xml = $(xml);

  $xml.find('categories browser').each(function(i, category) { 
    options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
  });

  $xml.find('ChartSeries series').each(function(i, series) {
    var pointOptions = {
        name : $(series).find('name').text(),
        y: Number($(series).find('value').text()),
        // drilldown: ... this should be defined drilldown optionally
    };

    options.series[0].data.push(pointOptions); //pushing point to the data, not to the series
  });

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});

 console.log(options.drilldown);
```

Edit:

Change axis type to category and dont define explicitly categories, so categories will be created dynamically based on a point's name.

```
    var options={
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
  },
  series : [{
    name:'Browsers',
    data:[]
}]
};

var url = "http://utils.highcharts.local/takie/chart.xml"

$.get(url, function(xml) {
  var $xml = $(xml);

  // $xml.find('categories browser').each(function(i, category) { 
  //   options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
// });

  $xml.find('ChartSeries series').each(function(i, series) {
   var pointOptions = {
     name : $(series).find('name').text(),
     y: Number($(series).find('value').text()),
     drilldown: $(series).find('name').text()
   };
   options.series[0].data.push(pointOptions);  
  });
  var drilldown={
   series:[]
  };

  $xml.find('ChartSeries series').each(function(i, series) {
    var pointOptionsDrill = {
        id : $(series).find('name').text(),
        data:[] 
    };

    $(series).find('drilldown').each(function(i,drilldownSeries){
     $(drilldownSeries).find('date item').each(function (i, item) {
        pointOptionsDrill.data.push([$(item).text()]);
    });

     $(drilldownSeries).find('data point').each(function (i, point) {
        pointOptionsDrill.data[i][1] = Number($(point).text());
    });

   });
    drilldown.series.push(pointOptionsDrill);  

  });
  options.drilldown=drilldown;
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function () {
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. That worked, i pushed it to the data of the series. And for the drilldown should i be doing the same. I have edited the code. please help.

Comment: Thank you morganfree! I almost made it, but i get this in  `options.drilldown` -> 
`drilldown : {"series":[{"id":"Apr-2016","data":[["01-Apr-16"],["02-Apr-16"],["03-Apr-16"]]},{"id":"May-2016","data":[["01-May-16"],["02-May-16"],["03-May-16"],["04-May-16"]]}]}`, But that doesnt make the chart to drilldown. Could you please help me sort my mistake.